# console.log( variable ); VS console.log( [variable] ); / One gives info the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, console.log

In Chrome, this gives the HTML tag:

```
var image = document.getElementsById('image');

console.log(image);
```

In Chrome, this gives all kinds of info such as `clientWidth` etc:

```
console.log([image]);
```

Why is this?

Comment: Clicking on the HTML tag should expand it, or let it inspect you in the DOM tab at least

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log` is a finicky method.  It's implemented however the browser team decides, since there's no formal spec ( last I checked ).

In the first `.log(image)` Chrome.console seems to run `.toString` (or equivalent) method on your HTMLElement and gives you the string output.

In the second `.log([image])` Chrome.console outputs the contents of the array as indexed objects/primitives.  It won't try to process the children of the array the same as a first-level argument to `log`, so it gives you the actual HTMLElement Object, not the string output.

Comment: As a side note, you can use `console.dir` to log the object without as much finicky behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(image);
```

This logs the direct reference to the `HTMLELement` in your document, showing the actual `<img>` *(or any other element)* tag.

```
console.log([image]);
```

Here you pass an `Array` as argument, which will log an array. The array simply shows you the `Object` of the `HTMLElement`.